# Conflicting serial interrupt with SD.h (arduino) and custom library Error: multiple definition of `__vector_18'

Tags: arduino-uno

For a project I am dependend on a certain libary. This library needs to do something with the serial interrupt which is fine on it's own. I tested the library and what it is supposed to do, functions perfectly fine.

But than I included <SD.h> and than this happened.

```
HardwareSerial0.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `Serial':

(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_18'
```

I know precisely what is going on. These lines of my custom library

```
#elif defined(SERIAL_PORT_0)
ISR(USART_RX_vect) {
    XpressNetClass::handle_interrupt(); //weiterreichen an die Funktion
}
```

conflicts somehow with the Sd.h library.

Now I looked into the SD library to see if I can 'remove' any conflicting code but I cannot find it. I looked into several header files which were mentioned in the sd library.. but it is such a large web with files I get lost.

I found the only other mentioning of

```
ISR(USART_RX_vect)
```

and it lies in HardwareSerial0.cpp. But I do not understand how SD.h ends up with using hardwareSerial0 somehow?

So I have 2 questions: Is this actually fixable? I would like to use both SD and SPI libraries and my custom library needs to do it's thing as well.

And if it is fixable. How can I fix this without breaking every other project?

I am compiling the code for an atmega328P.

Comment: your iSR conflicts with the ISR in HardwareSerial

Comment: Yes I know this already. But I do not understand how the Sd.h library is involved, Without the library, the project compiles fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within the folder in which the SD.h library lies. In this folder there is a file called SDfile.cpp and it contained one whole function with a couple of calls to Serial.print.

Commenting out all these lines, solves the conflict.